# traceback error message in blender 2.80

Tags: error

when I left click on any part of screen in blender to choose item it sends me this error message 
the last thing I did was weight paint to help with my rigging .[image]

```
file "/volumes/blender/blender.app/contents/resources/2.80/scripts/startup/bl_operators/wm.py",line 348.in execute
if contexts_path_validate(base,data_path) is Ellipsis: 
file "/volumes/blender/blender.app/contents/resources/2.80/scripts/startup/bl_operators/wm.py",line 83 in context_path_validate
value = eval("context %s " % data_path) if data_path else ellipsis 
file"<string>", line1 in <model>
attribute error : 'scene' object has no attribute 'exclude'
location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: This is the error message from your previous [closed question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170277/trace-back-error).  The message in image is not the same. _But is similar to previous, see my comment there_ Suggest trying _`File > Defaults > Restore Factory Settings`_ as it is possible one of your addons is causing this.

Comment: when I tried File > Defaults > Restore Factory Settings it deleted my mesh

Comment: After restore defaults, open your saved file and see if error persists.

Comment: yes error is still there it just delete all my saved files

Comment: Restore factory settings does not delete any saved files. Restore an autosave file. Also recommend you update to at least 2.81.

Comment: I did load factory settings and it worked out thank you